# Retrieving tasktracker logs for a particular job programatically

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata, oozie, webhdfs

Hi am working with OozieClient API.
I need to retrieve the task tracker logs for a particular workflow job using the OozieClient API. If not with OozieClient API any other way using a program is also fine. As of now with the OozieClient i am able to get the job log using client.getJobLog(), but i need task tracker logs and not job logs. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Try retrieving the yarn application Id from oozie using OozieClient API.

Once you have this ID you can make a call to history server using its rest api/or history server's client library, to fetch the Log dir path using "jobAttempts" api.

Now you can browse this directory using hadoop client.